# Changing the value of a pointed to integer in C

Tags: c, heap-memory

I want to declare a new integer in the heap,

```
int *intPtr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

How do I change the value of the space in the heap, to which `*intPtr` points to?
Thanks

Comment: You might find this useful: http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Comment: And there's also the [Binky Pointer](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereference `intPtr`:

```
*intPtr = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need to cast the result of malloc. malloc returns a void* and the void* is casted implicitly to any pointer (int*, char*, ...).

So :

```
int *intPtr = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

You can also write :

```
int *intPtr = malloc(sizeof *intPtr);
```

---

If you want to change the value pointed by intPtr, just use the dereference operator '*' like :

```
*intPtr = <new_value>
```

where  is your new integer value.